# Is there a "function comprehension" to change a value in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Data is a list of lists, ig. `[[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]`

I have these two lines which get an average of `val[0]` in a list data based on if `val[1]` is `0`

```py
l = [val[0] for val in data if val[1] == 0]
return sum(l)/len(l)
```

**Is there a way to calculate the sum while doing the list comprehension?**

Comment: `s = sum(val[0] for val in data if val[1] == 0)`?

Comment: You can use a loop

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych since you don't have the list afterwards you can't divide by length to get an average.

Comment: `functools.reduce`? Of course Guido will hate you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague to me but I'm trying to give some information...

List-comprehension is supposed to create a list for you. "A syntax which creates lists". So it really depends on which value you need to exist after the iteration. Is it just the average? the result list? the sum?

If you want to have the result list *and* the sum while you're iterating, you can use a for loop instead:

```py
data = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [4, 0]]

lst = []
total = 0
for v1, v2 in data:
    if v2 == 0:
        total += v1
        lst.append(v1)
```

If you insist to do it in a list comprehension, you can do:

```py
data = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [4, 0]]
total = 0

def sum_up(n):
    global total
    total += n

lst = [sum_up(v1) or v1 for v1, v2 in data if v2 == 0]
```

Here the return value of the `sum_up` is `None` which is Falsy so the result list contains the value of `v1` and you have `total` as well.

If you just intend to squeeze it in one line and have the result list *and* the average:

```py
print(sum(l := [v1 for v1, v2 in data if v2 == 0]) / len(l))
```

Here because of walrus operator you have access to the result list `l`.

In the first two approaches the calculation of the sum happens while iterating through the `data`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to calculate the `sum`, you can directly calculate the mean (average). At least this is what your code suggests you are actually doing with dividing `sum` by `len`.

```
import statistics

data = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
return statistics.mean((val[0] for val in data if val[1] == 0))
```

Comment: From the user's perspective one function is called but `mean` in turn calculates the sum and count in pure Python.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP probably wants because he calls `return sum(l)/len(l)` at the end of his code.

Comment: The bold sentence says they want to have the sum *while* the iteration in the list comp is taking place not after that. But yes their question needs more details.

Comment: From my experience on SO, beginners ask many X-Y questions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem ... From the code sample I understood that he wants to calculate the average and he got the idea that the most effective way is to calculate sum while creating the comprehension. Well, it is not. In Python, there is usually a simple solution to every simple problem, so we can go straight to the point instead of reinventing wheels.